# Callback refs not trigger when ref value changes in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using useCallback to observer ref callback value changes but I getting only one node printed in console. How I can observer ref value changes ?

```
  const myRef = useRef(null);

  const refObserver = useCallback(node => {
    if (node) {
      console.log(node); // print one time only 
    }
  }, []); 

  return (
    <>
       <div ref={refCb => {
           myRef.current = refCb;
           refObserver(refCb);
       }}>
          Hello world!
       </div>

       <button onClick={() => {
          myRef.current.innerText = `${Math.random()}`;
       }}>
          Change text!
       </button>
    </>
  )
```

Comment: What makes you think the ref callback will be executed more than once? Your component has no re-rendering logic

Answer (score 2):

Nothing in your component would trigger a re-render so the ref callback will only be executed when the component is mounted or unmounted.

Use state instead of directly mutating DOM properties (ie `innerText`) in order to use React's render cycle

```jsx
const [text, setText] = useState("Hello world!");

const refObserver = (node) => {
  if (node) {
    console.log("[refObserver]", node);
  }
};

return (
  <>
    <div ref={refObserver}>{text}</div>

    <button type="button" onClick={() => setText(Math.random())}>
      Change text!
    </button>
  </>
);
```

[image: Edit sharp-shockley-mtlycv]